# Different Twig-Layout for Authentication in special controller?

Tags: symfony, templates, authentication, twig

I open a modal with an iFrame, which serve restriced pages of a special controller. So, when I'm not logged in, the iFrame redirects to the general login-route, which actually extends the standard-layout file.

Now, what I want to achieve is, that if the the user isn't logged in and opens up the modal, the login/registration page should extend a different layout (without navigation bar etc.).

So, how can I set a different layout for the authentication views, only if the user is redirected to it through the modal? Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pass along a request parameter from the IFrame, to let the controller know that the request came from the modal, e.g. `path/to/your/page?ref=modal-iframe`:

Then in the controller I would check if the request parameter is present and correct or the user is logged in. In that case you go on outputing your template, otherwise redirect to the general login route.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
     /*
     * @Template("YourBundle:User:login_registration.html.twig")
     */
     public function myAction(Request $request)
     {
         $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');

         if (($request->get('ref') && $request->get('ref') == 'modal-iframe') || 
                    $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
              return array();
         }
         else {
             return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('login'));
         }
     }
}
```

The template would then take care of loading the correct layout, depending on whether the user is logged in or not:

```
{% extends (app.user ? "layout1.html" : "layout2.html") %}
```

Comment: do you know how i can add a parameter to the login-redirect route, before it redirects?

Comment: Like this: `$this->generateUrl('login', array('param1'=>'val1', 'param2'=>'val2' ...))`

Comment: No, when the Redirect ist automatically executed (to login of user is not logged in)...